# How can I make a button that adds a character to the text of a label, and then check the text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

I'm trying to make some buttons add text to a label, and then have another button check the text of the label so that it then creates an event.
It is something like writing a key with characters, and if you write the correct one, an event is made.
Tried to see and learned that it can be done easily with a tk.Entry, but the problem is that I don't want the text to be able to be modified, except for the buttons. that's why I put it in a Label.
help me please?

```
import tkinter as tk


def a():
    trad.config(text="a")
    
    #global i
    #sal.insert(i, valor)
    #i += 1



ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("Bosque")
ventana.geometry('900x800')
ventana.resizable(0,0)


sal = "¿Qué camino debería tomar?"

trad = tk.Label(ventana,text=sal,wraplength=200,anchor="n")
trad.config(bg="#137420", fg="#E59866",font=("Verdana",10,"bold","italic"),width=25, height=9)
trad.place(x=660,y=160)

#caja = tk.Entry(ventana, width=37)
#caja.place(x=660,y=200)


boton = tk.Button(text="  ↑  ",font=("Verdana",17), command=a)
boton.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton.place(x=745,y=330)

boton1 = tk.Button(text="  ↓  ",font=("Verdana",17))
boton1.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton1.place(x=745,y=423)

boton2 = tk.Button(text="  Ir  ",font=("Verdana",16))
boton2.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton2.place(x=746,y=379)

boton3 = tk.Button(text=" → " ,font=("Verdana",17))
boton3.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton3.place(x=812,y=376)

boton4 = tk.Button(text=" ← ",font=("Verdana",17))
boton4.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton4.place(x=686,y=376)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: `trad.config(text=trad["text"]+"a")` or `trad["text"] += "a"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you can do is pass a value in the command when the button is pressed, and change the label text then according to that.
For passing an argument in command of the buttons, you can use `lambda`

```
import tkinter as tk


def a(value):
    if value==1:
        trad.config(text="a")
    elif value==2:
        trad.config(text="b")
    elif value==3:
        trad.config(text="c")
    elif value==4:
        trad.config(text="d")
    elif value==5:
        trad.config(text="e")
    #global i
    #sal.insert(i, valor)
    #i += 1



ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("Bosque")
ventana.geometry('900x800')
ventana.resizable(0,0)


sal = "¿Qué camino debería tomar?"

trad = tk.Label(ventana,text=sal,wraplength=200,anchor="n")
trad.config(bg="#137420", fg="#E59866",font=("Verdana",10,"bold","italic"),width=25, height=9)
trad.place(x=660,y=160)

#caja = tk.Entry(ventana, width=37)
#caja.place(x=660,y=200)


boton = tk.Button(text="  ↑  ",font=("Verdana",17), command=lambda:a(1))
boton.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton.place(x=745,y=330)

boton1 = tk.Button(text="  ↓  ",font=("Verdana",17), command=lambda:a(2))
boton1.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton1.place(x=745,y=423)

boton2 = tk.Button(text="  Ir  ",font=("Verdana",16), command=lambda:a(3))
boton2.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton2.place(x=746,y=379)

boton3 = tk.Button(text=" → " ,font=("Verdana",17), command=lambda:a(4))
boton3.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton3.place(x=812,y=376)

boton4 = tk.Button(text=" ← ",font=("Verdana",17), command=lambda:a(5))
boton4.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton4.place(x=686,y=376)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Then later, to check the text, use either `trad["text"]`, or (preferred mostly) use `trad.cget("text")` to get its value.

Use such methods mentioned above to first get the text of Label, then add new text to it before configuring Label's text in your function-

```
def a(value):
  textInLabel = trad.cget("text")   #get the text already present in label
  if value==1:
     newText = textInLabel + " a"      #set the text to add in Label
     trad.config(text=newText)         #add the new text to the label's text
   elif...
```

Comment: thank you :). how can I make each key add a character to the label without replacing it?

Comment: Edited the answer with an explanation to your query.